# Getting a different model from Retrofit based on enum

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, retrofit

I'm working on a project and this is the first time I've had to deal with enums being returned from Retrofit. Basically, I have an API that is returning an enum. Here's what the API returns:

[image]

From here, I have a model that looks like this:

[image]

And here is the FeedEnum data class:

[image]

I've not had to do this with Retrofit before and am confused about what approach to take. A lot of my searching online hasn't shown much about this topic, which is also annoying. For extra info, I'm also using Kotlinx Serialization.

So what I'm basically asking, how do I go about changing the model of the data in ActivityModel based on the enum that the API is returning?

EDIT: I've tried making a parent model and having child models that inherit from this. This *sort of* works. I just then can't access the child model's members, which is essential for the rest of the project.

I've read somewhere to just make a big data class with all possible attributes thrown in as nullable and then I know which I need by checking "type". This would probably work but seems super sloppy but if it's the only way, then whatever.

Ideally I'd like to have some kind of data type I can throw in for "data" in ActivityModel but there's not much I can find online.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?

Comment: How do I go about changing which model I use for the data based on the enum the API returns?